# Remove `/node` from front page when using a template file (page--front.tpl.php)

Tags: uri

As it stands I have no content going to the front page, i am simply using a template file for the front. When I sign out and sign in as any role of user on my site my front page url turns into:
`www.mysite.com/node`

I do not want this behavior, and have tried several methods but nothing seems to work.

I have tried adding this snippet to setting.php:

`function custom_url_rewrite_inbound(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
  if ($path == 'node') {
    $result = ''; 
  }
}`

I have tried creating a custom module and have tried every suggestion from https://www.drupal.org/node/500296 nothing works.

I have encountered this behavior before, and to solve the issue i added the 
[Node Page Disable](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_page_disable) module and deselected the `Retain /node as an active url?` checkbox which removed the `/node` from the home page URL.

Now when I implement the module and deselect the checkbox and save the form, the checkbox goes back to being selected after the form is submitted. I cannot figure out what is going on, I have cleared every cache known to man-kind, used different machines and operating systems so obviously something is conflicting. I just don't know where to look.

I cannot post a bug/issue to the module page because drupal site is currently broken for creating new users... This is a nightmare. If anyone could give me some insight on possible conflicts or have any crazy ideas how I could get around removing this useless `/node` from the home page after a user signs in; it would mean the world to me. Thanks regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) and it seems to do the trick. I'll still accept someone else's answer if anyone can give any insight on what might of been the solution to my original issue.